# Why aren't there notifications about negative reputation changes?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, notifications

Occassionally, my posts get down-voted. However, most of the time they are up-voted.

When I get a positive reputation change, you get a notification at the top of the site that says `+whatever reputation` for things like up-votes, accepts and edits. However, when you lose reputation, you have to notice your reputation go down strangely and then actively look in your reputation history to see where the down-vote came from.

So my question is, bearing in mind that there are notifications for positive changes in green; surely it would be logical to notify negative reputation changes in red for example?

Comment: I, along with other users, agree with you. Getting notified of reputation loss is a valuable way of keeping your answer quality in check, In that respect, it is more valuable than gain notification.

Comment: I agree as well, and will add that I'd like notification of non-counted up or down votes, ones that come in after hitting the 200 point ceiling.