# How many people who downvote actually know that it takes a point of their own rep too?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes

Considering the number of increasing down-votes across all SE sites (and especially StackOverflow), it really makes me wonder how many users who just "casually" down-vote other's answers know this fact that it takes down two points from their own account.

If you consider my own example, I usually never down-vote unless there is something totally wrong with the concerned answer (though I've had others down-vote my own answers for no apparent reason). But since I came to know this fact a few days ago, I've stopped doing that too. Why should I down-vote to improvise someone else's situation, if it affects my own reputation too? Isn't that a fair question?

I think we should advertise this fact more and more that down-voting actually costs the caster too. We will surely see a reduction in those "casual" down-votes cast just because someone had a fight with spouse at the morning breakfast.

## Update

Okay, I did not know that the single negative point to the caster is only applicable for answers, not questions. Otherwise, I would not have asked this question in the first place, in a forum that allows the whims of anonymous users to overwhelm a question with downvotes. Had downvoting this question cost you a point, I bet you wouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @Pralad: You know that comment is a standard invitation for heavy downvotes?

Comment: You might not think there's any apparent reason when others downvote you, just as they don't think there's any reason why someone would downvote them. But there are, and they do.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for commenting! I did not know that meta is full of anonymous cowards who just enjoy downvoting others without even explaining why they do so. I still don't get it whats wrong with this question.

Comment: Votig on meta express disagreement and doesn't *always* mean that your question is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you're getting downvotes because there's something totally wrong with the concerned premise

Comment: A on-topic question should not be down-voted. The querer, by definition, may not know whether the premise is right or wrong, thats the reason he is asking the question in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't there notifications about negative reputation changes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227210/why-arent-there-notifications-about-negative-reputation-changes)

Comment: How will users know they are wrong unless they are told they are wrong?

Comment: Also, it's generally a good idea to get a feel of how a community works, rather than attempting to push your ideals onto it.  Especially one that's been discussed to death such as, "down-vote only with comments".  There are **many** reasons why comments aren't necessary.

Comment: True, but there is certainly something wrong with a model that allows someone's reputation to get damaged at the whims and fantasies of anonymous voters.

Comment: If you apply one negative vote to the caster on answers, why don't you apply the same to questions? Isn't it evident that in both cases, the rep damage to the caster's target is equal?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free

Comment: Read this comment from [systempuntoout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144912/systempuntoout) in the linked answer: **"Please, don't give free bullets to everyone or the number of "care to explain the downvote?" comments will saturate the RAM of your Database servers."**

Comment: Because the quality of the content is more important than ensuring every user gets help.  The primary focus of SE is to build a repository of high quality information.  You might help users in the process, but that's just a beneficial side effect.  Content > users.

Comment: But your concept of **content** is flawed when you say that. Had your content be backed by the up/downvotes of only High-rep users (as the answerer suggested), I would have agreed with you. But your definition of **content** that depends on the whims of anonymous voters is not something that relates to **Quality** very well.

Comment: There is a **massive** amount of discussion about this.  We are not obligated to re-hash it to the satisfaction of everyone who asks.  I would highly recommend doing some research about how and why SE works the way it does before you go attempting to criticize the methodology.  And, really, we get something like two users a week suggesting making comments mandatory for downvotes.  It just gets tiresome.

Comment: Summing up your words: *"Whims and fantasies of coward anonymous voters who had a fight with the spouse on the morning breakfast"*, yeah, that's pretty much the wrong definition of voting.

Comment: I don't understand how you guys are able to reach this question to cast your downvotes? 11 hours ago and still Downvotes pouring in? As if SE has found no one else to make a grudge against today.

Comment: The breakfast effect, @PrahladYeri :P

Comment: @brasofilo - Its not breakfast effect, its called `free effect`. They are downvoting only cause its free to downvote a querer's reputation to the point of misery. Downvoting a question should not be `free`!

Comment: @Prahlad people are trying to close it (wrongfully) as duplicate, this put the question in a close queue so bringing some more attention and probably more downvotes.

Answer (score 14):

Your question is based on a false premise.

Down voting questions doesn't cost you, the caster, anything.

Down voting answers cost you one reputation point.

The recipient of the down-vote loses 2 points in both cases.

This is well known by regular users of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I've removed the linked question and edited, so it falls in the correct premise now.